# Change completion status of a survey programmatically

Tags: 2010, survey-list

I need to change the completion status of a survey programmatically.

The *completed* field of a survey is a computed one, and therefore cannot be changed. I checked its XML schema and found this:

```
<Field
  Name="Completed"
  Type="Computed"
  ... snip ...
>
  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef Name="_Level"/>
  </FieldRefs>
  <DisplayPattern>
    <Switch>
      <Expr>
        <Column Name="_Level"/>
      </Expr>
      <Case Value="255">No</Case>
      <Default>Yes</Default>
    </Switch>
  </DisplayPattern>
</Field>
```

So I thought I could solve my problem easily by just changing that *_Level* field value to 255. However, whenever I try to change it, I get an Exception without any meaningful message. Checking the correlation id in the logs, I see that the SQL Server threw an Excetion with the following message:

> @tp_Level is not a parameter for procedure proc_AddListItem.

Does anyody know of a way to change the value of the *Level* field, or any other way to change a survey completion status programmatically? I wish to avoid touching any SQL because we are going to deploy the solution to a Sharepoint Online environment.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am stuck with the same error now :(

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande Unfortunately, no. It seems like this is not possible.